# Apache pig in Cygwin

Tags: windows, hadoop, cygwin, apache-pig

Is there any sources available for running Apache in Cygwin. With the latest Hadoop version i was able to setup a hadoop cluster in windows machine successfully, but I can't make PIG run in a cygwin terminal. The following error returns while attempting invoking pig grunt.

```
 $ pig -x local

cygwin warning:

  MS-DOS style path detected: c:\pig/conf/pig.properties

  Preferred POSIX equivalent is: /cygdrive/c/pig/conf/pig.properties

  CYGWIN environment variable option "nodosfilewarning" turns off this warning.

  Consult the user's guide for more details about POSIX paths:

    http://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using.html#using-pathnames
cygpath: cannot create short name of C:\pig\logs
Cannot locate pig-withouthadoop.jar. do 'ant jar-withouthadoop', and try again.
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Given the warnings it looks like pig is a windows tool, not natively built in Cygwin? Did you follow the setup instructions for cygwin at https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.7.0/setup.html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve the above error, I have rebuild pig for hadoop-2.2.0 as described in the below link and able to get rid of the exception.

http://javatute.com/javatute/faces/post/hadoop/2014/installing-pig-11-for-hadoop-2-on-ubuntu-12-lts.xhtml